# Getting Error in Angular js + Type Script in http put status 400 using DNN7

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, typescript, dotnetnuke-7, typescript1.4

I have implememnted a controller using angular js and type script using dot net nuke 7.and trying to call my web api method using http.put but getting error in status as 400.
Here is my controller code:-

```
var customerapp = angular.module('CustomerSearch');
module CustomerSearch.controllers
{
    export class CustomerCtrl {
        static $inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache'];
        debugger;
        constructor(protected $scope: ICustomerScope,
            protected $http: ng.IHttpService,
            protected $templateCache: ng.ITemplateCacheService) {
            $scope.search = this.search;
            console.log(angular.element($scope).scope());
        }
        public search = (search: any) => {
            debugger;
           var Search = {
                ActId: search.txtAct,
                checkActiveOnly: search.checkActiveOnly,
                checkParentsOnly: search.checkParentsOnly,
                listCustomerType: search.listCustomerType
            };

            this.$scope.customer = [];
            this.$scope.ticket = [];
            this.$scope.services = [];


            this.$http.put('<%=ResolveUrl("~/API/Search/PutDoSearch")%>', Search).
                success((data, status, headers, config) => {
                debugger;
                this.$scope.cust_File = data[0].customers;
                this.$scope.ticket_file = data[0].tickets;
                this.$scope.service_file = data[0].services;
            }).
                error((data, status) => {
                debugger;
                console.log("Request Failed");
                alert(status);
                });

        }
    }
    var customerapp = angular.module("CustomerSearch", []);
    customerapp.controller('CustomerCtrl', CustomerSearch.controllers.CustomerCtrl);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide full stack trace of error?

Comment: I have putted my status in alert it gives me 400 ?

Comment: I don't think <%=ResolveUrl("~/API/Search/PutDoSearch")%> can be used in typescript file. You should provide correct url.

Comment: But it's the only syntax i can use in dotnetnuke framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of

```
this.$http.put('<%=ResolveUrl("~/API/Search/PutDoSearch")%>', Search)
```

And instead use:

```
this.$http.put("/API/Search/PutDoSearch", Search)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need have the server parse `<%=ResolveUrl("~/API/Search/PutDoSearch")%>` for you.

One way you can do this put in a script tag e.g.

```
<script>
       var doSearchUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/API/Search/PutDoSearch")%>';
</script>
```

Then within your typescript have

```
// At the root of your file
declare var doSearchUrl:string; 

// And later
this.$http.put(doSearchUrl, Search)
```

Comment: hello barsat thanx for your time but where i have define these script on my view page or where, and about declaration as well i tried to do the same in my controller and declare it at last where i have defined my angular app but it gives me error of "Undefined"